# What is compound indexing and how do I use it properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, compound-index

I have a really slow query that repeats itself quite a bit. I've tried indexing the individual fields but it doesn't seem to help. The CPU usage is still very high and the queries still appear on the slow query log. It seems I need a compound index?

How would I index the following query properly?

```
select *
from `to_attachments` left join
     `attachments`
     on `to_attachments`.`attachment_id` = `attachments`.`id`
where `to_attachments`.`object_type` = 'communicator' and `to_attachments`.`object_id` = '64328'
order by `attachments`.`created_at` desc;
```

EXPLAIN Result: 

`1   SIMPLE  to_attachments  index   NULL    PRIMARY 775 NULL    244384 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  attachments eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   quote.to_attachments.attachment_id  1   NULL`

Index For to_attachments
[image]

Comment: You should qualify all column names so other people know where the columns come from.

Comment: Qualify!? Meaning?

Comment: Nobody can understand those columns belongs to which table. Put the table structure of those 2 tables.

Comment: Ahh, got it. I added table names to the join.

Comment: can you put the EXPLAIN result?

Comment: Explain result? Again, what do you mean?

Comment: `EXPLAIN select *
from to_attachments left join
     attachments
     on to_attachments.attachment_id = attachments.id
where to_attachments.object_type = 'communicator' and to_attachments.object_id = '64328'
order by attachments.created_at desc;` execute this you will see what indexes are used in the query execution

Comment: Thank you. I added that.

Comment: More on building indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want indexes on `to_attachments(object_type, object_id, attachment_id)` and `attachments(id)`.

Comment: Thanks, though, I have this already and I'm still seeing these in the slow query log and eating up cpu, hence I had thought about compound indexes which I don't know much about.

Comment: @Quesofat:  the *order* of the columns in the index is important. an index with a leading column of `attachment_id` is not equivalent to an index with a leading column of `object_type` or `object_id`.  Gordon's recommendation is based on the equality comparisons in the WHERE clause.  If `object_id` is more selective (more unique) than `object_type`, then for a large table, i'd opt for an index  on `to_attachments(object_id,object_type,attachment_id)` but I suspect that wont be much different than Gordon's recommendation. +10

Answer (score 1):

You sequence of the index is wrong it should be (object_type, object_id, attachment_id). In the multicolumn index order of the columns in the index is MATTER.